# Keras metric equivalent to scikit learn's average precision score metric

Tags: keras, scikit-learn

I've had a look at the Keras metrics documentation and couldn't find an equivalent to scikit learn's [average precision score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html) metric (which I think is the same as the area under the precision-recall curve, AUPRC). It isn't the same as the average_precision_at_k, I believe unless someone can correct me on that.

Comment: here are listed all available metrics for keras: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c2e36f369b411ad1d0a40ac096fe35f73b9dffd3/keras/metrics.py

Answer (score 5):

Late answer, but I was facing the same issue recently.

You can use the [AUC metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC) with the parameter `curve` . Something like:

```
AUC(curve='PR')
```

Comment: This saved me loads of time, thanks! Should also be noted that the tensorflow version applies some interpolation so may differ from the sklearn metric.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom metrics for keras to be passed at the compilation step. (https://keras.io/metrics/) The function would need to take (y_true, y_pred) as arguments and return a single tensor value.

Here is an implementation of average_precision for keras:

```
import keras.backend as K

def average_precision(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision
```

Comment: I think this is just precision... not quite what i'm looking for, which is also known as AUPRC or area under the precision-recall curve. But good tip about implementing one's own metric..

Comment: you can also use tf.py_func for that : tf.py_func(your_metric, [y_true, y_pred], tf.float64)